# Why my Notes app project doesn't instantiate a note object in the recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a basic notes app. I took reference from a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tu7ZiRozZNs) but the video was in kotlin but I am using java. So, I am having problems in displaying the saved notes. The YouTube video was explaining the app architecture components of an android app. Here is my [GitHub](https://github.com/gautam84/Notes) link to the project. And here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.test.notes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NotesRVAdapter.INotesRVAdapter {

    private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    NotesRVAdapter adapter = new NotesRVAdapter(new NotesRVAdapter.WordDiff());
    EditText input;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input = findViewById(R.id.input);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



        noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);

        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, notes -> {
           if(notes != null){
               adapter.updateList(notes);
           }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(Note note) {
        noteViewModel.delete(note);
        Toast.makeText(this, "note deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void submitData(View view) {
        String noteText = input.getText().toString();
        if(!noteText.isEmpty()){
            noteViewModel.insert(new Note(noteText));
            Toast.makeText(this, "note added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know much about this, but one thing that is bugging me is the onCreate being of type protected. Is it supposed to be?

Comment: Ofcourse it is.